# Mocking IUnitOfWork and IRepository<T> for Unit Test

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, unit-testing

**Explanation**

The implementation of both interfaces goes for `UnitOfWork` and `Repository<T>`. Since repository is generic, I'm struggling whether to **keep multiple refereces** of `Repository` inside my `UnitOfWork` (for each entity), **or** **a single generic method** that returns the correct one (currently it is this way).

The issue is in my said **method**:

```
// In the controller, this method is called like this
// Student student = unitOfWork.Repository<Student>().GetByID(id);

// UnitOfWork.cs
public IRepository<TEntity> Repository<TEntity>() where TEntity : class {
    return new Repository<TEntity>(dbcontext);
}

// MockUnitOfWork.cs
public IRepository<TEntity> Repository<TEntity>() where TEntity : class {
    return new MockRepository<TEntity>();
}
```

The problem is `MockRepository`, as it works with a `List`. Since I'm returning a new instance, I can't keep track if the new inserted object is on the list (in case of POST CREATE operation).

```
// MockRepository.cs
public IList<TEntity> Entities { get; private set; }
```

**Questions**

Up to this point I see two possible reasons of this problem:

1. I should not be testing if the created entity is on the list, since that's a mock. Which means `MockRepository.Add()` would have an empty body.
2. I should keep a reference for every repository in my `UnitOfWork` instead of returning a new instance each time. Which means every time I add a new entity to my domain model, I have to update `UnitOfWork` code with a reference and initialization for the new entity.

**Conclusion**

If the issue is No. 1, how should I test it worked, beside asserting `viewResult.ViewName == "Index"` or similar?

Comment: I think you shouldn't always return new repositories, not even in the real UoW. Keep track of the repositories you created per type (e.g. in a dictionary) and return the one you created before if it's there.

Comment: You should go with option 2 by caching the repository in a Dictionary<Type, IRepository<TEntity>> when they are created.